# How to remove not-selected area in html with 0px font size and text-align:justify sytle in the parent tag

Tags: html, css

I am developing a HTML page which has hidden copyright sentences in the HTML. While the copyright sentences are always attached Ctrl-C & V copied text, these are not shown in the web browser because the font-size is 0px. The simple HTML code is below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
             p {text-align: justify;}
             dummy {font-size:0px;}
             normal {font-size:10px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <normal>This is an original text to be displayed for users.</normal> 
            <dummy>Copyrights is all reserved by Company ABC</dummy>
            <normal>This sentences includes copyrights text inside.</normal> 
            <dummy>Copyrights is all reserved by Company ABC</dummy>
            <normal>But there is unseleced space between normal text and dummytext</normal>
            <dummy>Copyrights is all reserved by Company ABC</dummy> 
            <normal>This is occurred only when the 'text-align' sets to 'justfify'</normal>
            <normal>And it disappears when &lth1&gt tag is inserted</normal>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML code is rendered in the web browser with following figure after pressing Ctrl+A (selected all)

[image: Screen shot for the not selected area with the HTML]

As you can see, there are unselected area between <normal> and <dummy> tags.
It occurrs only when the text-align css of <p> is set to 'justify'.

Or if a head tag such as <h4> is inserted in front of the <p> tag, the unselected areas are disappeared.

```
...    
        <h4> Uoops! </h4>
        <p>
            <normal>This is an original text to be displayed for users.</normal>
...
```

[image: Screen shot for the all selected with <h4> tag]

[Question]
How to remove the unselected blank area on 0px text when the parent css for text-align is set to justify, without a trick such as adding <h4>?

Comment: have you tried `dummy {display: none !important;}`

Comment: display:none is not a solution. Becuase the dummy sentences should be copyed when ctrl+c&v. If display:none is set, the dummy sentences become not part of the html text, anymore.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand the question at the begaining.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, those elements should not be inside a p element (see W3C validator for fuller info). However, replacing them with spans and classes did not remove the problem so no solution yet!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try it.

```
dummy {
  font-size: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but it's not legal HTML (can't have the dummy tag inside a p tag according to W3C Validator). If you change to spans and classes (including, slightly weirdly, the inline-block proposed in this answer) then it works and seems to be legal.

Comment: Great! Thank you Yochanan Sheinberger! It works for me too. I have spent all my time to resolve this problem for 2 days. You saved my project. Thank you again.

Comment: A Haworth, Thanks for the comment. I'll consider to change this structure using span tag with class for the correct HTML syntax.